# Close XML file without saving

Tags: excel, vba

I have *xlsm file which generates *xml file and then imports it to the system. An XML file remains open in the background. However, I want that after the code is run, both *xlsm and *xml files are closed without saving. Here is the code:

```
Sub XML_Preparation()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

(main code part)
.......
.......
.......
.......

MsgBox ("Your list has been uploaded into iScala! The requisition number is " & Worksheets("CODES").Range("A68").value)

Workbooks("BBH_RequisitionUpload_Type5.xlsm").Close True
Workbooks("BBH_ReqType5_1.xml").Close False


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close will be enough? Check your parameters.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work.  Anyway, thank you.

Comment: What [it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)?

Comment: How do you generate the xml file? Suggest to edit the essential code parts in your post. - If only in memory without prior possible saving, there'd be no need to "close". @NuranaH.Novruzova